# Mysql results from multiple tables where ids match don't appear

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have a database with 5 tables:
users,
drives,
clients,
drivers,
vehicles.

And I'm trying to fetch all the drives with their corresponding vehicle driver and client.
I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT drives.id,
drives.driver AS driver_id,
CONCAT(LEFT(drivers.name, 1), '. ', drivers.surname) AS driver_name,
drives.client AS client_id,
CONCAT(LEFT(clients.name, 1), '. ', clients.surname) AS client_name,
drives.vehicle AS vehicle_id,
vehicles.license_plates AS license_plates,
drives.departure,
drives.destination,
drives.distance,
drives.type,
drives.payment_type,
drives.timestamp,
drives.total,
drives.expenses,
drives.profit,
CASE
    WHEN DATE(drives.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) AND drives.total > 0 THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN DATE(drives.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) AND drives.total = 0 THEN 'Overdue'
    WHEN DATE(drives.timestamp) >= DATE(NOW()) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN drives.total = 0 THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN drives.total > 0 THEN 'Prepaid'
        END     
END AS payment_status,
DATE_FORMAT(drives.timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'stamp'
FROM drives, clients, drivers, vehicles WHERE 
drives.driver = drivers.id AND
drives.client = clients.id AND
drives.vehicle = vehicles.id AND
drives.user = '146' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 9999999999 OFFSET 0
```

Everything works fine, however if I delete a vehicle record from vehicles table and then try to fetch all the drive records from table drives, the drive records which had drives.vehicle = vehicle.id (that no longer exists) will not be printed out.

As you can understand this is not what I want. I want all the drive records to be printed out even if a vehicle,client,driver gets deleted.

Data example of drives table:

```
id  timestamp               user    driver  client  vehicle departure   destination distance    type        payment_type    total   expenses    profit  note
1   2013-02-14 10:33:26     146     1       1       1       Address 1   Address 2   0           Deprature   Cash            0       0           0       hello world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using INNER JOIN, consider using OUTER JOIN

```
...
FROM drives 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON drives.client = clients.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN drivers  ON drives.driver = drivers.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicles ON drives.vehicle = vehicles.id
WHERE
....
```

Comment: May I ask is there an "ON" missing from the last join ?

Comment: Sure, there must be ON

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JOINS here, this will surely help for capturing the NULL values, `LEFT JOIN` should help

```
SELECT DRI.id, DRI.driver AS driver_id, CONCAT(LEFT(DI.name, 1), '. ', DI.surname) AS driver_name,
DRI.client AS client_id, CONCAT(LEFT(CI.name, 1), '. ', CI.surname) AS client_name,
DRI.vehicle AS vehicle_id, vehicles.license_plates AS license_plates, DRI.departure,
DRI.destination, DRI.distance, DRI.type, DRI.payment_type, DRI.timestamp, DRI.total,
DRI.expenses, DRI.profit,
CASE
    WHEN DATE(DRI.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) AND DRI.total > 0 THEN 'Completed'
    WHEN DATE(DRI.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) AND DRI.total = 0 THEN 'Overdue'
    WHEN DATE(DRI.timestamp) >= DATE(NOW()) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN DRI.total = 0 THEN 'Pending'
            WHEN DRI.total > 0 THEN 'Prepaid'
        END     
END AS payment_status,
DATE_FORMAT(DRI.timestamp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS 'stamp'
FROM drives DRI
LEFT JOIN clients CI ON DRI.client = CI.id
LEFT JOIN drivers DI ON DRI.driver = DI.id,
LEFT JOIN vehicles VI ON DRI.vehicle = VI.id
WHERE
DRI.user = '146'
ORDER BY DRI.id ASC
```

Comment: sql gives me the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN vehicles VI ON DRI.vehicle = vehicles.id WHERE drives.user = '146' ORD' at line 19

Comment: Updated the query, can you try now